# When I try to import a React component - I get empty object

Tags: reactjs, webpack, npm-package

I have this very basic component, in my standalone.js file:

```
import React from "react"

function MyPromosComponent() {
  console.log('PHK - IN MY PROMOS COMPONENT');
  return <h1>TEST FROM MY PROMOS</h1>;
}

export default MyPromosComponent;
```

And I'm building it with this minimal webpack configuration:

```
module.exports = {
    output: {
          path: __dirname,
          filename: "dist/index.js",
          libraryTarget: "var",
          jsonpFunction: "webpack_jsonp_gbundles"
    },
    entry: {
        main: './src/standalone'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                // exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/i,
                // exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                // exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: "babel-loader",
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

In my package.json I have `main: "dist/index.js"` - so I should be able to use it as a module.

However, when I install it in another project and import it - I get this:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components)
or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check your code at App.js:19.
in App (at src/index.js:6)
```

And in App.js I have:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

import MyPromosComponent from 'my-promos-page-client';

function App() {

  console.log('PHK ??? ', MyPromosComponent);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>TEST</h1>
      <MyPromosComponent /> <-- line 19 in App.js
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Any idea what could be wrong? ... Cause I'm doing the export as a default one.

Or probably there is something wrong with my webpack.config file?

Comment: Please show the code and import causing the error.

Comment: @AndyRay - I just edited my question with the code where I'm importing the component.

Comment: so what does `console.log` shows you in the `App`?

Comment: An empty object ...